# does an article precede a numeral adjective?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I know that we cannot put an indefinite article before a plural word but, what if there is "one" before a numeral adjective noun phrase?

> "a one boy"
>
> "one boy"
>
> "a one mass grave"
>
> "one mass grave"

Answer (score 2):

a = one

So, you put either of them.

> a boy **OR** one boy

However, you must learn that at times, they are **not** interchangeable, though they could be (grammatically), semantically it'll look a bit odd.

Say, in **general** context,

> He's a wonderful person **over** He is one wonderful person.

However, 'a' is **possible** with 'one' but then, the case is different

> I'm **a** one-man army

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, I can say that 'a' before 'one' is a redundancy. You can either use 'one boy' or 'a boy'(if you want to make it look less specific). Same is the case with 'one intelligent(or any adjective) boy' or 'an intelligent boy'.
We can put an article before the plural in cases like 'the Shaastri sisters' or 'the monuments in Delhi'. Note that 'the' is also an article and that it is used for even more specificity. 'a' and 'an' are singular non-specific articles but 'the' is a singular/plural specific article .
Hope that cleared the confusion!